# Problems Installing Git with Snow Leopard

Tags: git

I started thenewboston tutorial on Git so I can start using it. I have Snow Leopard and downloaded git from http://git-scm.com/download/mac and opened the package...but now I don't know what to do. I checked to see if it was installed with my terminal, but when I did the git command all that came up was illegal instruction.

This is what I see after I have opened the package: 1) ReadMe.txt, 2) uninstall.sh, 3) git-2.0.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.pkg, and 4) setup git PATH for non-terminal programs.sh

I clicked on the pkg and ran through the instructions and it said it had been successfully installed, but it's not working like I said in terminal. What did I do wrong/what can I do to get it up and running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same problem. It is because the last version of Git for Mac, 2.0.1, doesn't work with Snow Leopard. I installed a previous version and it works perfectly.
You can go to [this page](https://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/) and download the last one (which is the most recent) of the previous versions: git-1.8.4.2-intel-universal-snow-leopard.dmg. 
It worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and `brew install git` once you have the [developer tools](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed.

Comment: I wish I could, but when I try to download the app this error message pops up: Xcode can't be installed on Macintosh HD because Mac OS X version 10.8.4 or later is required. I have a old old mac air (planning on upgrading soon) and it won't let me download apps. Anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just open the package file? You'll need to double click the "git-2.0.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.pkg" and follow the instructions there to install it.

Comment: Yea and it told me that the installation was successful which is why I got lost and wasn't sure what to do next

Answer (score 0):

After you click on download package you will see mounted drive.
In this mounted drive click on "git-2.0.1-intel-universal-snow-leopard.pkg" and follow installation process.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/sh739igiarp7h5a/Screenshot%202014-07-14%2019.54.42.png

Comment: Thanks for responding! I did do that, ran through the instructions and it told me the installation was successful, but somehow it seems like its not working cause I can't use git

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, hold down the Control key, right click on the package and choose "Open." When the package opens with the warning, there will now be an option to allow you to install.